# Não consigo pegar o value de uma combobox com WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Não consigo pegar o value de uma combobox com WPF. Como eu faço para pegar o value? Esse é o código da combobox no XAML.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxCereais" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Milho"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Soja"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Feijão"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: já? Rápido para downvote. Ok ficou ampla, vou remover uma possível resposta e deixar apenas uma pergunta.

Comment: Não fui eu quem votou. Mas não consegui entender qual o problema que você está tendo.

Comment: a pergunta estava ampla mesmo e editei. Cara, procurei na internet e não achei. O que eu quero é, tenho itens em minha combobox, tipo, Milho, Soja, Feijão, Trigo e cada item desse deveria ter um value e poder pegar esse value e passar como parâmetro. Consigo pegar o content, mas não o value, porque não consegui defini-lo.

Answer (score 1):

É preciso fazer um *cast* para um `ComboBoxItem`.

```
var item = cbxCereais.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem;
var text = item.Content.ToString();
```

Isso ocorre pois os itens de um `ComboBox` são tratados como objetos do tipo `ComboBoxItem`. Fazendo o *cast* conforme informado e acessando a propriedade `Content`, resolve o problema.

#### Buscando a propriedade Name/Value

> Complementando a resposta após ter entendido o que foi pedido depois de comentários feitos.

Para buscar o "value" de um ComboBoxItem, podemos usar a propriedade Name:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxCereais" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Milho" Name="M" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Soja" Name="S" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Feijão" Name="F" />
</ComboBox>
```

E no código:

```
var item = cbxCereais.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem;
var text = item.Name;
```

Comment: Content não me resolve, pois Content vai retornar Milho e não M, como desejado. Já fiz e foi isso que retornou.

Comment: E onde você escreveu que quer que retorne M e não Milho? Nos comentários da pergunta não me ajuda. Edite a pergunta e escreva o que realmente quer que aconteça.

Comment: O Value e como eu disse, como eu faria com web e com winform. Como eu faço para pegar o value?  Essa é a dica para isso, o value.

Comment: E porque postou um código em WPF se quer em winforms e web?

Comment: Cara, leia os comentários e os posts. Eu quero em WPF e disse que gostaria de fazer em WPF como hoje eu faço com WEB e WinForm. Isso tá bem lúcido. Já encontrei a solução e postei a solução. Acho que paro por aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, consegui resolver. Entendi que no WPF existe é a propriedade Name e não Value, por isso eu não conseguia. Veja a solução:

```
ComboBoxItem ComboItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbxCereais.SelectedItem;
            string name = ComboItem.Name;
            lblTeste.Content = name;
```

E assim está no meu XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxCereais" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Milho" Name="M"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Soja" Name="S"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Feijão" Name="F"/>
        </ComboBox>
```